# Scripting languages and interfacing to C APIs

Tags: c++, c

What scripting languages can only interface to libraries that implement a C API? Assume we won't be using SWIG or other third-party tool. One example of such a scripting language is Lua.

Comment: What is as scripting language?  What have you done to investigate yourself?  Avoiding simple lookup work is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: I refer you to the wikipedia page for details on what a scripting language is (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language). I did a lot of research before I posed this. However the question is part of a wider and more general inquiry into the use of C and C++ APIs in the programming community. I have one question for you regarding SO, if an answer can be found on the internet, should the corresponding question be asked on SO?

Comment: Did you mean "what scripting languages can interface directly to a C api using only pure C" (ie. Do not force the use of eg. Swig) or "what scripting languages can only interface to C" ie. cannot interface to any language other than C

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.*"

Comment: My question was what scripting languages can interface directly to a C compatible API, but not necessarily written in C. Eg Object Pascal can create C compatible APIs and so can FORTRAN 77 and many other languages.

Comment: @Frxstrem Ok understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all the major languages have a runtime based in C and require you to directly or indirectly through FFI interface through a C API/ABI, these include but are not limited to the following.

- Squirrel
- Lua
- Ruby
- Python
- JavaScript

Comment: One other scripting language that I found that required interfacing via a C API was Julia. I also know that the compiled language Free  Pascal also needs a C API to call out to.